# Alexa Skills Decision Trees

Tags: decision-tree, alexa-skills-kit

On creation of a lambda function for a Decision Tree, the execution of the Test Event generates an error.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/var/task/index'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)"
  ]
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Links: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/TxHGKH09BL2VA1/New-Alexa-Skills-Kit-Template-Step-by-Step-Guide-to-Build-a-Decision-Tree-Skill
https://github.com/tartanguru/alexa-assistant/issues/8

Comment: where is your code? Did you compress the files properly? Remember you have to make a zip of all the files, and not the folder in which your files are.

Comment: @NikhilWagh, thanks for the help. I understand that my necessary files would have been missing when I was simply editing the file. So, this time when I created the lambda function, I chose Serverless Application Repository and then https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-fact and simply edited the function according to my requirement.